# How to add domain security certification, in WordPress website?

Tags: urls, security, dashboard

When I visit website using Wordpress Dashboard, browser is showing 'cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority';

[image]

But, when I access it directly typing the domain in the URL Bar, no Certification icon is being displayed.

[image]

What it means? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, clear the browser cache because overhere it shows nicely. You did all well it seems.

Answer (score 1):

"Not Secure" warning refers to the lack of security for the connection to the page that you are visiting. It suggests that the information sent and received with that page can be exploited by the hackers.

Have you done the follow things?

1. Getting an SSL certificate
2. Installing your certificate through your web host
3. Changing your WordPress URL
4. Implementing a site-wide 301 redirect

If the answer is yes, there might be an issue with the cache. Try clearing it. It should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your website has a SSL issued by cPanel, I think if you redirect your non-SSL site to the SSL version it will work. You can add these lines to your `.htaccess` file to get it done.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.tld/$1 [R,L]
```

You can also install a plugin called **Really Simple SSL** from WordPress directory to do this if you are not comfortable editing server files.

Do let me know the outcome, I will be looking forward to your reply.